# Strapi Admin on Heroku not opening even after disabling brotli in /config/middleware.js

Tags: heroku, strapi

Followed the documentation for deploying on Heroku  and added a middleware  `appname.herokuapp.com` still takes forever to start.

i followed this [issues8375](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/8375) and the docs.

my middleware.js

```
module.exports = {
    settings: {
      gzip: {
        enabled: true,
        options: {
          br: false
        }
      }
    },
  };
```

/config/env/production/database.js

```
const parse = require('pg-connection-string').parse;
const config = parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
default: {
  connector: 'bookshelf',
  settings: {
    client: 'postgres',
    host: config.host,
    port: config.port,
    database: config.database,
    username: config.user,
    password: config.password,
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  },
  options: {
    ssl: true,
  },
},
  },
});

/config/env/production/server.js
    module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
        url: env('HEROKU_URL'),
      });
```

The `/admin has` not openend even after 10mins on heroku.

Logs at `heroku logs --tail -a appname`

```
 2021-04-27T08:01:39.461994+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/main.88d9c53d.chunk.js" host=appname.herokuapp.com request_id=d63f32b0-aed3-4d40-b0aa-36ed1e1c734c fwd="62.8.85.117" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=606ms status=200 bytes=2563045 protocol=https
```

Comment: Add your logs so that anyone can understand what's happening in the backend. To print your logs in Heroku run command `heroku logs --tail -a appname`

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a way around this so did a redeploy following [Alex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbh3-G1jIUg&ab_channel=AlextheEntreprenerd)

I left the /config/middleware.js as is,

```
module.exports = {
    settings: {
      gzip: {
        enabled: true,
        options: {
          br: false
        }
      }
    },
  };
```